# Omitting headings without properties from orgmode TaskJuggler export

Tags: org-mode

Using org-mode 8.0.3 and TaskJuggler 3. I would like to be able to mix notes with TaskJuggler information in an org-mode file (in true literate programming style). Like this (pseudocode):

```
* Project             :taskjuggler_project:
  * Task 1
     :PROPERTIES:...
     * SubTask
       :PROPERTIES:...
     * Meeting Notes
     * Journal
  * Task 2
     :PROPERTIES:...
```

The sections without TaskJuggler-specific properties (Meeting Notes and Journal) still get exported to the tjp file and appear in my reports.

I would like:

- Ideally, to exclude the Meeting Notes and Journal from my tjp file
- If that's not possible, an easy way to hide them from my reports in the TaskJuggler report definitions. I have the report definitions in a tji file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `:noexport:` tag on the headlines you don't want exported?

This will prevent them from exporting regardless of the exporter type, although you can remove the tag when exporting to another format that you do want that content included (if you ever do so).

See [Export Settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings), specifically the section on `Exclude Tags` for more details.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. It's a bit unwieldy because of switching between text and TaskJuggler export, but maybe it's the best there is right now. Thanks.